# iPhone: How to add extra objects and keys to existing array of dictionaries?

Tags: iphone, arrays, dictionary, key

I have several arrays of dictionaries containing address and contact details.  I would like to cycle through each array of dictionaries and look up each address' location and store their corresponding longitude and latitude.  So for any array of dictionaries, I want to be able to *append* two additional keys "longitude" and "latitude" with the respective values.

At the moment, I create a new dictionary, read each key and value [including the new longitude and latitude] and then write a whole new array.  Seems too convoluted. Is there a better way?

```
        //copy into new array
    [dict setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Category"]      forKey:@"Category"];
    [dict setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Name"]          forKey:@"Name"];
    [dict setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Address"]       forKey:@"Address"];
    [dict setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"PhoneNumber"]   forKey:@"PhoneNumber"];
    [dict setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"ContactTitle"]  forKey:@"ContactTitle"];
    [dict setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"ContactName"]   forKey:@"ContactName"];

//APPENDING LOCATION KEYS AND DATA

    [dict setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Longitude"]  forKey:@"Longitude"];
    [dict setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Latitude"]       forKey:@"Latitude"];

    [masterArrayWithDistance addObject:[dict copy]];
```

Comment: maybe a better idea is to have a temp `myObject = [array objectAtIndex:x]` instead of accessing the array once for every key?

Comment: or a temp `NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[array objectAtIndex:x]];` and add the new objects to that and insert it into the master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a mutableCopy of your array/dictionary.

```
NSMutableArray *copyArray = [originalArray mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *copyDic = [[array objectAtIndex:x] mutableCopy];
[copyDic setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Longitude"]  forKey:@"Longitude"];
[copyDic setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Latitude"]       forKey:@"Latitude"];
```

And then you can replace old dictionaries/arrays with the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: dict];
[d setObject: newLongitude forKey: @"Longitude"];
[d setObject: newLatitude forKey: @"Latitude"];
[masterArrayWithDistance addObject: d];
```

Also, not sure why you needed to copy the dictionary in the first place. `addObject:` would just keep a reference.